# Writing to global DataFrame - variables does not work when running several functions in multiprocess

Tags: python, multiprocessing

The task is to parallelize two functions that should form two different dataframes at the output. The problem is that parallel processes do not write results to global variables. There is the following code.

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocess as mp
manager = mp.Manager()

df_build = pd.DataFrame()

df_0 = df_1 = manager.Value(pd.DataFrame, df_build)

df_test = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(0,9),
                        'b': range(10,19),
                        'c': range(100,109),
                        'd': range(200,209)})

def frame_0(x = df_0):
    x = x.append(df_test[0:2])
    print('result frame_0','\n', x)
    return x
    
def frame_1(y = df_1):
    y = y.append(df_test[2:4])
    print('result frame_1','\n', y)
    return y

starts_thread = mp.Process(target = frame_0, args = ())
finishes_thread = mp.Process(target = frame_1, args = ())
starts_thread.start()
finishes_thread.start()
starts_thread.join()
finishes_thread.join()    

print('DF_0',df_0, '\n'
      'DF_1', df_1)
```

End output -

```
AttributeError: 'ValueProxy' object has no attribute 'append'
DF_0 Value(<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: []) 
DF_1 Value(<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>, Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [])
```

The problem is that - when both functions are run simultaneously, data slices are not written to prepared global variables are not written to global variables, because ValueProxy don't have append.
I tried to work with the multiprocess.manager, where slices were written to lists

```
import multiprocess as mp
manager = mp.Manager()


a = manager.list()
b = manager.list()
print('this_one_should_be_empty',a,b)

def list_0(x = a):
    for i in range(10):
        x.append(i)
  #  print(x)
    return x
    
def list_1(y = b):
    for i in range(10):
        y.append(i)
 #   print(y)
    y 
    return y

print('function_pass')
starts_thread = mp.Process(target = list_0, args = ())
finishes_thread = mp.Process(target = list_1, args = ())
starts_thread.start()
finishes_thread.start()
starts_thread.join()
finishes_thread.join()    
print('multiprocess_calculation_complete')

print('final_list', '\n',a, '\n', b)
```

and it works, but is possible to make a similar record in two parallel functions to the frame structure?
I'd be grateful if someone could tell me where I'm wrong.

Comment: why can't you just use `threading` and be able to append to the dataframe from 2 threads ? what are you actually trying to do ?

Comment: `threading` can't get around python's internal GIL restrictions, it only can be passed by `multiprocessing`. I try to run two function in parallel, fill in both two different DataFrame with different data, then work with this two filled DataFrame as global variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution - broadcast to Namespace instead of Value and add type of variable to Namespace.
Full code -

```
import pandas as pd
import multiprocess as mp
manager = mp.Manager()

df_0 = manager.Namespace()
df_1 = manager.Namespace()
df_0.df = df_1.df = pd.DataFrame()

df_test = pd.DataFrame({'a': range(0,9),
                        'b': range(10,19),
                        'c': range(100,109),
                        'd': range(200,209)})

def frame_0():
    df_0.df = df_0.df.append(df_test[0:2])
  
def frame_1():
    df_1.df = df_1.df.append(df_test[2:4])

starts_thread = mp.Process(target = frame_0, args = ())
finishes_thread = mp.Process(target = frame_1, args = ())
starts_thread.start()
finishes_thread.start()
starts_thread.join()
finishes_thread.join()    

print('DF_0',df_0.df, '\n'
      'DF_1', df_1.df)
```

Comment: Trust me, running this in a single process and thread will be orders of magnitude faster than using the namespace.